# validating 2d-array in request

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

This is my request:

```
name: max
phone: 06132219899
mobile: 07113105802
bank[0][card]: 11
bank[0][acc]: 22
bank[1][card]: 44
bank[1][acc]: 44
```

I want to validate data inside `bank`. I've tried:

```
'bank'=>'required|array' , 
'bank.card'=>'required|digits:11' ,
'bank.acc'=>'required|digits:24'
```

But it doesn't work , I just get:

> The `x` field is required.

Comment: Does it work with `bank.*.card` and `bank.*.acc`? Right now, you don't have a `bank.card` or `bank.acc` field being passed.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks its working , pleas post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When validating arrays, you need to specify the index of the array validation rule, either with a specific number (by dynamically constructing the rules via looping the input) or using a wildcard `*`:

```
$rules = [
  "bank" => "required|array",
  "bank.*.card" => "required|digits:11",
  "bank.*.acc" => "required|digits:24"
];
```

Note: if looping, you'd have `bank.0.card`, `bank.1.card`, etc. The only real benefit to this is easier to reference error messages on the front-end.